# Why still need local port forwarding for SSH tunneling

Tags: ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

IIUC, dynamic port forwarding supports all the use case of local port forwarding, I am curious whether there are still some use cases of it that dynamic port forwarding cannot do?

Comment: Hi and welcome to UL.se!

IIRC dynamic port fowarding uses a SOCKS proxy. So all use cases that cannot or don't want to use a SOCKS proxy cannot use dynamic port forwarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to U&L. I just did some reading[[1]](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-dynamic-port-forwarding), having never herd of dynamic port forwardig, and it is quite intersting. Definitely something to add to my tolbox.

To answer your question, I can think of three reasons to continue to use local port forwarding:

1. Dynamic Port Forwarding uses socks, which requires client support. While this can be worked around using port to socks proxy tools, at that point you might as well use SSH Local Port Forwarding. While this might not be an issue for many sysadmin tasks, that is not the only use for Port Forwarding. Gaming the first usecase to come to mind, butvthere are shurly others.
2. Local Port Forwarding works fine most of the time. Unless their is a clear benifit to switching to Dynamic Port Forwarding, it usually isn't worth the time to switch to a new process. On the other hand I can very well think of reasons why a process might switch to Local Port Forwarding from Dynamic Port Forwarding.
3. Older systems may not support Dynamic Port Forwarding, or may have had it explicitly disabled during an upgrade for security reasonscompleteness. the same could be said for Local Port Forwarding, butI am including it for completenes.

[1] https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-dynamic-port-forwarding